# net use - System error 1920 has occurred

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, network-share

On Windows Server 2008 R2, when I run the following command I am getting the 1920. I've tried pretty much everything I am aware of and I can't figure out what causes the error. When I try to map the same network share using the UI and same credentials, everything works fine.

```
net use * \\EAAA-12345\C$\ /USER:\\EAAA-12345\Administrator Passw0rd /PERSISTENT:NO
```

Anybody knows how to get rid of the 1920 error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the back-slash after the C$ and remove the back-slash between USER: and EAAA-12345.

So it should look like this:

```
net use * \\EAAA-12345\C$ /USER:EAAA-12345\Administrator Passw0rd /PERSISTENT:NO
```

Comment: Check the OP's question's edit history -- they did have `\\` there, but the block quote markdown ate it. ;) I updated the question.

Comment: @jscott, Still need to remove the \\ between USER: and EAAA-12345

Comment: I didn't want to edit the syntax OP supplied, as that may be integral to their issue, I just corrected the markdown formatting. :)

Comment: @jscott, had a mind hick up and thought you were the OP. I'll edit my comment to reflect your changes.

Comment: It seems markdown is a wicked temptress, it ate the double slashes in my first comment as well, I even used the backticks-of-protection!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was due to a corrupted DNS suffix, in the VPN Ethernet adapter. check your network settings.

Control Panel --> Network and Sharing Center --> right click on the relevant Ethernet adapter --> Properties --> Internet Protocol version 4 --> Properties --> Advanced

Try also:cmd -> `ipconfig /flushdns`